# Function returning set of records from one of two queries depending on argument

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I've got a problem in this function:

```
create function fruit(proses varchar)
returns table("FRUIT" varchar, "ID" integer, "FRUITCOLOR" varchar) as
            -- i think i miss something in this part
$$
begin
  if proses = 'view1' then
    select fruit, id from table;
  elseif proses = 'view2' then
    select fruit, id, fruitcolor from table
  end if;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

I want to use one of two `SELECT` queries but it doesn't work, I think the mistake is in `returns table` but I don't know where exactly.

Comment: Do you want to create a view or do you want to return a set of records from a function which can be used like a view?

Comment: actually, i want to make 2 view, but i don't know how, the returns table is doesn't work

Comment: The schema of tables returned in the `if-else` clause are different. You should probably modify it to `if proses = 'view1' then select fruit, id,null from table;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to return a set of rows from a table through a function. Your code is mostly correct, but you forgot to [`RETURN QUERY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) from the function:

```
create function fruit(proses varchar)
returns table("FRUIT" varchar, "ID" integer, "FRUITCOLOR" varchar) as $$
begin
  if proses = 'view1' then
    RETURN QUERY select fruit, id, NULL from table;
  elseif proses = 'view2' then
    RETURN QUERY select fruit, id, fruitcolor from table;
  end if;
  RETURN;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

Note that you can only return a single "type" from any given function, so in case `proses = 'view1'`, you should return `NULL` as the third column.

You can now use your function as if it were any other table or view:

```
SELECT id, fruit FROM fruit('view1');
```

Comment: sorry, i got another problem here,
the view2 , i want take it from another table, help me :(

Comment: @AnitaWulandari Can't you simply change the query for 'view2' in the function above? You can edit your question above with more details if you have some problem. If it is more complicated than that, please make a new question.

Comment: sorry, but i've try someway but it can't, postgre said that structure of query does not match function result type,

it's same just like this function, but `fruitcolor` is from table2

Comment: Edit your question and put the definition of the table that you select the rows from (the table used inside the function). (Note that you can edit your question, it is the grey word 'edit' below your question.)